# Is there a way to write data to GA360 platform using Reporting Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking for a way to write data extracted from Google BigQuery to Analytics platform.

I have tried finding out documentation or API to write the data to Analytics Platform. It seems only read property for reporting is available.

Links:- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analyticsreporting/v4/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py

Comment: Include what you have tried so far

Comment: @Coder, I cannot move further without knowing the answer to my question. I have researched a way to write but I did not find. The links I have put are showing me only reading data from platform and not writing back on it! I hope I am clear there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) to write data to GA properties.

Comment: thanks, it helps. It seems that we cannot write back whatever data (CRM data) we want then. It must be from the list of already provided GA data.

Comment: Yea GA isn't mean to be a CRM. What you would do in this case is to use a custom dimension to store the CRM user id OR even the user id feature combined with the measurement protocol to "connect" the CRM data with the GA data.